# Puppeteer not working anymore in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I have an Azure Function where I convert an HTML to PDF and then download the result.

Yesterday I updated the function to version 4 and .NET 6 and I also saw that the `BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision` is obsoleted and I replaced it with recommended `BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision` and the function is not working anymore after publish.

I also tried locally but there is all good. The error I received is `Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.` and I suspect the Puppeteer.

This is my `Startup` function code:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
     var bfOptions = new BrowserFetcherOptions();
     if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
     {
          bfOptions.Path = Path.GetFullPath("mounted");
     }

     var bf = new BrowserFetcher(bfOptions);

     try
     {
          bf.DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision).Wait();
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
          string zipPath = Path.Combine(bf.DownloadsFolder, $"download-{bf.Platform}-{BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision}.zip");
          string folderPath = Path.Combine(bf.DownloadsFolder, $"{bf.Platform}-{BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision}");

          using (var process = new Process())
          {
               process.StartInfo.FileName = "unzip";
               process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"\"{zipPath}\" -d \"{folderPath}\"";
               process.Start();
               process.WaitForExit();
          }

          new FileInfo(zipPath).Delete();
     }

     builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
     builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPdfPrinterService>((s) =>
     {
               return new ChromiumPdfPrinterService(bf.GetExecutablePath(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision));
     });            
}
```

Has anyone else faced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. That was caused by RazorLight upgrade to stable version 2.0.0.

Rollback to version 2.0.0-rc.3 works fine.

Here is the GitHub issue: https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight/issues/481